# Installing of graphics.h library

Tags: software-installation, graphics, dependencies, gcc

When I try to install the following packages using this command

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev
```

it shows

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libasound2-dev : Depends: libasound2 (= 1.2.3.2-1ubuntu3)
 libpulse-dev : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.2-1ubuntu1) but 1:13.99.2-1ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
                Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (= 1:13.99.2-1ubuntu1) but 1:13.99.2-1ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[image]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: You haven't provided your release, but I'd check your package lists are up-to-date (ie. `sudo apt update` & ensure it's updated, no errors & your mirror is up-to-date).  A package I looked up is *out-dated* for what I suspect/believe is your release, but given you didn't provide that - your release could also be your issue (ie. check your sources), but you should provide release info for this type of issue.. Your package details don't align with any (*updated*) release for what I looked up.

Comment: No erros were found while updating as sudo apt update